# Installing Django on Bluehost

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm wanting to use django on bluehost, and I've gotten as far as installing python 2.7, then running `python get-pip.py`to install / update pip. And now hoping to install virtualenv; the instructions say to run `sudo pip install virtualenv` but neither the sudo or non-sudo version of this command works.

Sudo is flat out not permitted on Bluehost's shared hosting environment, and when I type `pip`, I get `command not found`. So I am to assume pip is still not installed, despite the successful execution of 
`python get-pip.py`

When I type `which pip` I get nothing, while `which easy_install`
gives me a path.

So is it there? I'm quite confused.

I've been stuck for some time. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Setting up Django on shared hosting like Bluehost isn't recommended. I would consider using another host. Look for either a VPS where you have root access so will be able to install the required packages, or a platform as a service like Heroku.

Comment: ... or something docker based.

Comment: I agree, but it's what I have for now.. I'd like to get it to work.

Comment: Also, fastcgi support was removed in Django 1.9, so I don't think it's even possible to get Django 1.9+ working on Bluehost. Django 1.8.X would be your only option.

Comment: They told me because the virtual environment relies on github, they can't install it. lol. Love this. Running locally and will move to new host as ready. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following command works for me when I want to run pip:

```
python -m pip install <package_name>
```